# Hierarchical list of custom taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy, terms, hierarchical

I have a custom hierarchical taxonomy. I don't know how many nested terms will be in each term.

What I want to do, is to list all taxonomy terms hierarchically no matter how deep each term is nested.

I already know how to do this for each level if I know the depth, but how can I rewrite my code so it will handle unlimited amount of nested terms?

```
foreach( get_terms( 'tax', array( 'parent' => 0 ) ) as $term ) {
  echo $term->name;
  foreach( get_terms( 'tax', array( 'parent' => $term->term_id ) ) as $child_term ) {
    echo $child_term->name;
    // of course I can do more foreach loops here for every lvl...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `wp_list_categories`, it can be used for any taxonomy, not only categories:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'tax'
);
wp_list_categories( $args );
```

See [the list of arguments in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories).